# ¿Elemento fuera de etiqueta main pero Outliner lo toma como dentro?

Tags: html

En un proyecto que debo hacer necesito que al pasar mi archivo html por un outliner todas las secciones queden con sus respectivos encabezados

Mi código es el siguiente:

```html
<main id="todasRecetas" class="contenedor"> (sería el padre)
      <article id="articulo1"> Articulo 1 - subencabezado 1 </article>
      <article id="articulo2"> Articulo 2 </article>
      <article id="articulo3"> Articulo 3 </article>
      <article id="articulo4"> Articulo 4 </article>

    </main>

    <article id="participanteGanador" class="contenedor">
     Articulo 5
    </article>
```

Al pasarlo por Outliner obtengo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo hacer que el articulo 5 quede como otro encabezado de la pagina y no un encabezado de la etiqueta main?

Comment: Stackoverfllow te proporciona una herramienta para que tu copies el código y ejecutes para así mirar el error que tienes, seria bueno idea que lo hicieras, saludos.. !!!

Comment: Disculpa soy nuevo acá y no tengo idea de donde encuentro lo que me dices, ¿eso sería en la misma pregunta?

Comment: [aqui hay una buena explicacion](https://www.humanlevel.com/articulos/desarrollo-web/el-outline-algorithm-de-html5.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomeindo que uses otros elementos y no main, te dejo un ejemplo.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<section id="todasRecetas" class="contenedor"> (sería el padre)
  <article id="articulo1"> Articulo 1 - subencabezado 1 </article>
  <article id="articulo2"> Articulo 2 </article>
  <article id="articulo3"> Articulo 3 </article>
  <article id="articulo4"> Articulo 4 </article>
</section>
<section>
<article id="participanteGanador" class="contenedor">
  Articulo 5
</article>
</section>
```

Si quisieras que tengan texto te dejo otro ejemplo:

```html
<section>
  <h1>La mosca</h1>    
  <p>El esta sección hablaremos de la mosca, una criatura adorable. 
    ... bla, bla, bla ...
  <section>
    <h2>Hábitat</h2>  
    <p>Únicamente se han divisado colonias de moscas en los montes de....
        ...bla, bla, bla ...
  </section>
</section>
<section>
  <h3>El mosquito</h3>
  <p>A continuación, otra rareza a punto de extinguirse, el mosquito. 
     ...bla, bla, bla...
</section>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, conseguí de manera parecida a la que me comentaste, primeramente intente cambiando la etiqueta main por section, pero tenía el error de que ahora, todo se mostraba como si estuviese contenido dentro de otro div que estaba por encima de estos, lo que hice fue simplemente cambiar el article que estaba fuera de main por un div, y todo parece estar bien de momento.

Comment: Si te fue util puedes marcar +1